# There are a lot of blank areas in the image generated by using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

When I use gnuplot to draw a picture, there is a lot of blank space in the bottom, I would like to make that space disappear or at least make it as minimum as possible. How can I do it by modifying my code?

[image]

My code is as follows：

```
set terminal postscript portrait color enhanced 15
set output "sites_nh3-2-daily_v3.ps"
set multiplot
set size 1, 0.2

cd "../../obs_mod/daily/"

set lmargin 3
set rmargin 1
set tmargin 2
set bmargin 1.5

set datafile missing ''
set datafile missing '-'

set autoscale
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m%d"
set format x "%m/%d"
set xrange["20220601":"20221230"]
set ytics offset 0.5,0

set ytics nomirror
set ytics font ",12"
set ytics offset 0.5,0
#set autoscale y                       # 根据数据动态调整y轴范围
set yrange [0:40]
set ytics 0,8,40
set xtics nomirror
set xtics font ",12"
set xtics offset 0.3,0
set border
set origin 0.0, 0.83
set label "JM-XQ" left at graph 0.03, graph 0.92 font ",12"
unset xtics
set key left at graph 0.72,0.94 font ",12"
set key reverse
plot "JM-xiqu.txt" u 1:($2) w p lc -1 pt 7 ps 0.3 t "obs", "" u 1:3 w l lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 1 t "mod\\\_base", "" u 1:4 w l lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 1 t "mod\\\_agr-NH_3"
unset label

set origin 0.0, 0.7033
set label "SZ-LHS" left at graph 0.03, graph 0.92 font ",12"
unset key
set yrange [0:10]
set ytics 0,2,8
plot "SZ-lianhuashan.txt" u 1:($2) w p lc -1 pt 7 ps 0.3 t "Obs", "" u 1:3 w l lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 1 t "mod_base", "" u 1:4 w l lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 1 t "mod\\\_noNH_3"
unset label

set origin 0.0, 0.576
set label "ZH-MH" left at graph 0.03, graph 0.92 font ",12"
unset key
set yrange [0:20]
set ytics 0,4,16
plot "ZH-meihua.txt" u 1:($2) w p lc -1 pt 7 ps 0.3 t "Obs", "" u 1:3 w l lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 1 t "mod_base", "" u 1:4 w l lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 1 t "mod\\\_noNH_3"
unset label

set origin 0.0, 0.449
set label "ZQ-SHWZ" left at graph 0.03, graph 0.92 font ",12"
unset key
set yrange [0:20]
set ytics 0,4,16
plot "ZQ-sihuiweizheng.txt" u 1:($2) w p lc -1 pt 7 ps 0.3 t "Obs", "" u 1:3 w l lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 1 t "mod_base", "" u 1:4 w l lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 1 t "mod\\\_noNH_3"
unset label

set origin 0.0, 0.322
set label "ZS-ZML" left at graph 0.03, graph 0.92 font ",12"
unset key
set yrange [0:15]
set ytics 0,3,12
set xtics nomirror
set xtics font ",12"
set xtics offset 0.3,0
set arrow from "20220701",0 to "20220701",75 nohead lt 0 lc rgb "gray0"
set arrow from "20220801",0 to "20220801",75 nohead lt 0 lc rgb "gray0"
set arrow from "20220901",0 to "20220901",75 nohead lt 0 lc rgb "gray0"
set arrow from "20221001",0 to "20221001",75 nohead lt 0 lc rgb "gray0"
set arrow from "20221101",0 to "20221101",75 nohead lt 0 lc rgb "gray0"
set arrow from "20221201",0 to "20221201",75 nohead lt 0 lc rgb "gray0"
plot "ZS-zimaling.txt" u 1:($2) w p lc -1 pt 7 ps 0.3 t "Obs", "" u 1:3 w l lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 1 t "mod_base", "" u 1:4 w l lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 1 t "mod\\\_noNH_3"
unset label
```

How should I set it in the code so that the generated picture will automatically not show the blank area?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the program explicit instructions how to place the lower limit of each plot:

```
set origin 0.0, 0.83
set origin 0.0, 0.7033
set origin 0.0, 0.576
set origin 0.0, 0.449
set origin 0.0, 0.322
```

If you want to move everything down, you will have to give smaller numbers for the y offsets.

On the other hand, if you are asking how to reserve less vertical space at the lower part of each one-fifth (from `set size 1.0, 0.2`) sub-plot, then maybe you want to replace the command `set bmargin 1.5` with `set bmargin 0`.  That will reduce appoximately 1.5 character heights of space at the bottom of each subplot.

Answer (score 0):

As Ethan already mentioned, you are setting the sizes and origins of the subplots manually. There is a more convenient option in gnuplot. Check the option `spacing` and `margins` in `help multiplot`:

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>   set multiplot
>       { title <page title> {font <fontspec>} {enhanced|noenhanced} }
>       { layout <rows>,<cols>
>         {rowsfirst|columnsfirst} {downwards|upwards}
>         {scale <xscale>{,<yscale>}} {offset <xoff>{,<yoff>}}
>         {margins <left>,<right>,<bottom>,<top>}
>         {spacing <xspacing>{,<yspacing>}}
>       }
> ```

Some comment:

- since you want zero spacing between the subplots, depending on the ytics it might happen that the first y-tic of the upper plot and the last y-tic of the lower plot might overlap. You avoided this, e.g. in the second plot, by explicitly setting `set ytics 0,2,8` although you have a range of `set yrange[0:10]`.With this, you hide the `10`-tic. Another way would be to use autotics but remove the `10` via `set ytics add ('' 10)`. I don't have yet a good idea when using autoscale/autotics but only remove the last tic label without knowing in advance what the range or value is.
- the multiplot margins by default are given in screen coordinates, however, you can also give the bottom margin in character dimensions `char 2` to provide just enough space for the xtic labels.

Check the following minimized and simplified example. I hope you can adapt it to your needs.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0)

```
### multiplots with zero spacing and only one x-axis label
reset session

set key top left
set xrange[0:100]
set format x ' '
set yrange[0:1.5]
set ytics 0.5
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 5,1 spacing 0,0 margins 0.07, 0.97, char 2, 0.98

    set label 1 "JM-XQ" at graph 0, graph 1 offset 1.5,-0.7
    plot '+' u 0:(rand(0)) w l ls 1
    
    set label 1 "SZ-LHS"
    set ytics add ('' 1.5)
    plot '+' u 0:(rand(0)) w l ls 2
     
    set label 1 "ZH-MH"
    plot '+' u 0:(rand(0)) w l ls 3
    
    set label 1 "ZQ-SHWZ"
    plot '+' u 0:(rand(0)) w l ls 4
    
    set label 1 "ZS-ZML"
    set format x "%g"
    plot '+' u 0:(rand(0)) w l ls 5

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]